# A formula by R.L.Graham,AMM(1995)

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I see this formula in a book, it comes from R.L.Graham,AMM(1995) :
$$\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\frac{1}{54^2}+\frac{1}{112^2}+\frac{1}{640^2}+\frac{1}{4032^2}+\frac{1}{10080^2}+\frac{1}{24192^2}+\frac{1}{40320^2}+\frac{1}{120960^2}$$
But I can not find this article in AMM(1955),can you help me to find which month it belongs to ?Thank you!

Addition:There is another example in Paul Erdos and Egyptian Fractions:

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/pre_Egyptian.pdf

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{1}{15^2}+\frac{1}{16^2}+\frac{1}{36^2}+\frac{1}{60^2}+\frac{1}{180^2}$$

[image]

And in [38]http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/64_07_reciprocals.pdf , I find a better formula:
$$\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{10^2}+\frac{1}{12^2}+\frac{1}{20^2}+\frac{1}{30^2}+\frac{1}{60^2}$$

$PS$: Since I have found the above papers,this problem has been less important.Thanks for your attention!

Comment: His papers are listed on http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/ and the only 1995 paper in the American Mathematical Monthly does not seem to contain this formula.

Comment: @TMM,thank you,I have found it before..And I have dowloaded all the AMM at 1955,but I didn't find his paper when I searched for his name.

Comment: Is it 1995 or 1955?!

Comment: @DonAntonio,the book says it's 1955.

Comment: Then please do edit your post accordingly!

Comment: @DonAntonio,thanks for your remind!

Comment: @Hecke What book is this from? It may be possible to reverse engineer the right citation.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo,from a popular science book in Chinese,which is my first language.